# beforeSave() to rename the file in yii(php)

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

I am using beforeSave() to rename the file thats been uploaded. but its not getting renamed before save into the folder. it has the same name as uploaded one.Iam using extension EAjaxUpload for uploading the file. can anyone help me where i have gone wrong... And i am working on windows.

In Model(AttachResume):-

```
protected function beforeSave()
{ 
                            $path='C:\\wamp\\www\\Myapp\\Resumes\\';
                        $uid=$_POST['AttachResume']['User_id'];
                        //var_dump($this->User_id); exit();
                        $file=$_POST['AttachResume']['ResumeName'];
                        //var_dump($this->ResumeName); exit();
                        $temp = $path.$file;
                        $newname=$uid.$file;
                        if(file_exists($temp)==true)
                        {
                          rename($temp, $path.$newname);

                        }
                 return parent::beforeSave();

  }  
Controller:-
 public function actionIndex()
{
    $model=new AttachResume;  
    if(isset($_POST['AttachResume']))
        {

         $model->User_id=$_POST['AttachResume']['User_id'];
     $model->ResumeName=$_POST['AttachResume']['ResumeName'];
     $model->save();

        }
       $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));
    }
```

Myapp is the aplication.Resume is the folder under it where i have to save documents,
Thanks

Comment: someone kindly help me out if i have gone wrong somewrhere.I an new to yii framework.

Comment: are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: yes im still looking for solution.. could you tell me what wnt wrong here...??

Comment: you want to rename the old, already uploaded file right?

Comment: Yes thats what i want.. sorry to have repleid late..

Comment: tried but couldn't figure out your mistake, just recheck all your values, and if the functions are getting called. haven't used that extension either, so i wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload/
Thats the best extension available

To rename the file being uploaded add this line below:
rename($folder.$result['filename'],$folder."newfilename");

Thanks to Ben:
Solution found on this link:
[How to use xupload with Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543909/how-to-use-xupload-with-yii)